# Is it possible to get anchor value through xpath?

Tags: xpath, http-unit

In my anchor tag, I don't have any id. But I need to get that value in Httpunit in-order to click.

Here is the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#">Continue</a>
```

Please let me know it clearly.

Comment: Sorry!!!

Here is the anchor tag,

<a href="#">Continue</a>

Comment: You might want to read the httpunit developer FAQ and search the unit tests for your example https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=5051BBF6.70700%40bitplan.com&forum_name=httpunit-develop

Answer (score 0):

you can actually get this like

```
//a[contains(.,'Continue')]

//a[starts-with(.,'Continue')]

//a[not(@id)]

//a[contains(@href,'#')]
```

what ever you like

i recommend you to see [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

and Google it before asking some very basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the anchor as part of the links supplied by WebResponse.getLinks ...

WebResponse page=wc.getResponse( ...
.. page.getLinks() ...